# CodeIgniter parsing multidemensional arrays

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, parsing, multidimensional-array, foreach

In this http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html tutorial we have this multidemensional array

```
$data = array(
          'blog_title'   => 'My Blog Title',
          'blog_heading' => 'My Blog Heading',
          'blog_entries' => array(
                                  array('title' => 'Title 1', 'body' => 'Body 1'),
                                  array('title' => 'Title 2', 'body' => 'Body 2'),
                                  array('title' => 'Title 3', 'body' => 'Body 3'),
                                  array('title' => 'Title 4', 'body' => 'Body 4'),
                                  array('title' => 'Title 5', 'body' => 'Body 5')
                                  )
        );
```

And we printing him easily like this

```
{blog_entries}
    <h5>{title}</h5>
    <p>{body}</p>
{/blog_entries}
```

But how to output array like this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/WniLT.png :?

```
 $data = array( 
array(
    'user' => array('id' => "1", 'name' => "Test1"
    ),'title' => 'Title 1', 'body' => 'Body 1'),
array(
    'user' => array('id' => "2", 'name' => "Test2"
    ),'title' => 'Title 2', 'body' => 'Body 2'),
array(
    'user' => array('id' => "3", 'name' => "Test3"
    ),'title' => 'Title 3', 'body' => 'Body 3')
);
```

If we trying to do something like this

```
{blog_entries}
    {user}
        {id}
    {/user}
    {title}
    {body}
    <br />
{/blog_entries}
```

We ll have error:

```
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Ah, found similar problem here [Extended Template Parser: CodeIgniter... Issue with Nested Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619523/extended-template-parser-codeigniter-issue-with-nested-arrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup your array more like this

```
$data = array( 'user' => array('id' => "1", 'name' => "Test1", 'title' => 'Title 1', 'body' => 'Body 1'),
                         array('id' => "2", 'name' => "Test2", 'title' => 'Title 2', 'body' => 'Body 2'),
                         array('id' => "3", 'name' => "Test3", 'title' => 'Title 3', 'body' => 'Body 3')
);
```

And after that, it's kind of like nesting HTML tags, except with key->value pairs in a PHP (If that make sense).

```
{user}
    <h4>{name} : {id}</h4>
    <span>{title}</span>
    <p>
        {body}
    </p>
{/user}
```

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is included in the built-in template class. (I don't know if it existed when you first posted the question, but it is in there now, I use it myself.) The trick is in creating the proper array structure to pass to the parser. I tested this example in a live page just now, works 100% in CI 2.1.3.

As a specific example, consider this code which displays (with minimal formatting) a series of rooms available at a hotel, and shows, per room, the rate(s) per day for each day of your travel. (2 days, in this example.)

```
{available_rooms}
    <p>{room_type} {total_rate}</p>
    {room_rates}
        <p>${room_rate} {room_date}</p>
    {/room_rates}
    <hr>
{/available_rooms}
```

With out put similar to:

```
1 King Bed 119.98
 59.99 2013-03-23
 59.99 2013-03-24

1 King Bed 119.98
 59.99 2013-03-23
 59.99 2013-03-24

2 Double Beds 139.98
 69.99 2013-03-23
 69.99 2013-03-24

2 Double Beds 139.98
 69.99 2013-03-23
 69.99 2013-03-24
```

This is the array I used successfully in this example.

```
> available_rooms > 0 > room_type = 1 King Bed 
> available_rooms > 0 > total_rate = 119.98 
> available_rooms > 0 > room_rates > 0 > room_rate = 59.99 
> available_rooms > 0 > room_rates > 0 > room_date = 2013-03-23 
> available_rooms > 0 > room_rates > 1 > room_rate = 59.99 
> available_rooms > 0 > room_rates > 1 > room_date = 2013-03-24 
> available_rooms > 1 > room_type = 1 King Bed 
> available_rooms > 1 > total_rate = 119.98 
> available_rooms > 1 > room_rates > 0 > room_rate = 59.99 
> available_rooms > 1 > room_rates > 0 > room_date = 2013-03-23 
> available_rooms > 1 > room_rates > 1 > room_rate = 59.99 
> available_rooms > 1 > room_rates > 1 > room_date = 2013-03-24 
> available_rooms > 2 > room_type = 2 Double Beds 
> available_rooms > 2 > total_rate = 139.98 
> available_rooms > 2 > room_rates > 0 > room_rate = 69.99 
> available_rooms > 2 > room_rates > 0 > room_date = 2013-03-23 
> available_rooms > 2 > room_rates > 1 > room_rate = 69.99 
> available_rooms > 2 > room_rates > 1 > room_date = 2013-03-24 
> available_rooms > 3 > room_type = 2 Double Beds 
> available_rooms > 3 > total_rate = 139.98 
> available_rooms > 3 > room_rates > 0 > room_rate = 69.99 
> available_rooms > 3 > room_rates > 0 > room_date = 2013-03-23 
> available_rooms > 3 > room_rates > 1 > room_rate = 69.99 
> available_rooms > 3 > room_rates > 1 > room_date = 2013-03-24
```